# Find the inverse of $f(x) = (x+1)/(x-8)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse

Find the inverse of this function: [image]

I have gotten this far:

$x = y+1/y-8$

$x(y-8) = y+1$

$x(y-8)-1=y$

$xy-8x - 1 = y$

I think I went backwards?

Comment: From your second equation, it looks like you mean $f(x) = (x + 1) / (x - 8)$; is this so? If not, then the manipulation isn't correct.

Comment: Well, All I did there was take the original equation and change f(x) (aka y) to x and all of the x's to y's

Comment: I meant the second line in the block of equations; it looks like you mutliplied by $y - 8$, which only makes sense if $y - 8$ is the denominator of the fraction.

Comment: I added a photo of the original problem. I can input the value, I am just having a hard time changing the function to the inverse.

Comment: If $y = f(x)$ is a function of $x$, you want $f^{-1}$ to be a function of $y$.

(Using your chosen inverted variables) 
Hint: $-8x - 1 = y - xy$, can you take it from there?

Comment: Bobby my head is spinning in circles, lol. How did you get to -8x - 1 = -xy?

Comment: The way you've chosen to "flip" your variables, solving for $y$ is actually solving for the inverse of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}$.

It seems that you understand that. But in order for this inverse to be useful (i.e. computing $f^{-1}(6)$), you need the inverse to be of only one variable.

Comment: $y=-8x - 1 / x$ Correct?

Comment: Ok, Can you show me how you took $ f(x)=(x+1)/(x−8)$ and got that down to : $-8x - 1 = -xy$. And $f^{-1}(6) = -49/6$ My math says that is wrong.

Comment: I did not say $-8x-1 = -xy$, I said $-8x-1 = y -xy$

Comment: Ok, my bad. Do you see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question did not ask to find the formula for $f^{-1}$, but only $f^{-1}(6)$, we simply let $f(x) = 6$:

$$6 = \frac{x+1}{x-8}$$
$$6x - 48 = x + 1$$
$$5x = 49$$
$$x = \frac{49}{5}$$

Therefore $f^{-1}(6) = \frac{49}{5}$.

---

Of course, for educational purposes, it is often useful to find the formula describing $f^{-1}$. Here is one way to do it:

$$f(x) = \frac{x + 1}{x - 8} = 1 + \frac{9}{x - 8}$$
$$f(x) - 1 = \frac{9}{x-8}$$
$$\frac{1}{f(x)-1} = \frac{x-8}{9}$$
$$\frac{9}{f(x)-1} = x-8$$
$$x = \frac{9}{f(x)-1} + 8$$

So

$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{9}{x  - 1} + 8$$

with $x \not = 1$.

Comment: In the 2nd part where did the $+\frac{9}{x-8}$ from?

Comment: $x + 1 = (x - 8) + 9$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)= (x+1)/(x-8)$ and we let $y=f(x)$, we can use your method of switching the variables $x$ and $y$ and solving for $y$.

You were correct in reaching $xy-8x-1 = y$. Though we have "solved" for $y$, this solution is not useful for finding the inverse of $f(x)$, because it is a function of two variables.

So you want $y$ to only be in terms of $x$.

$-8x-1 = y-xy$

$-8x-1 = y(1-x)$

$(-8x-1)/(1-x) = y$.

Remember this $y$ is **not** the $y=f(x)$ from the beginning, but rather we only named it $y$ so that we could solve for it. Once solved, you can give its proper name, $f^{-1}(y)$. This function takes a $y$, and spits back the $x$ used to form it.

I'll leave it to you to find $f^{-1}(6)$.

Also be careful with your manipulation.

$y+1/y-8 \neq (y+1)/(y-8)$.